# how to center items in glidejs without change settings

Tags: javascript, glidejs

As is seem image below, total item slot is 7, but source are dynamic and sometimes its 3 or 4..
How to centeralize these items properly using glidejs

[image]

Source code preview:

```js
<Slider element="glide" options={{ perView: 7 }}>
    {Object.entries(subSliderItems)
    .map(([key, value]) => (
        <div className="glide__slide" key={key}>
        <BoxSubCategory label={key} url={value} />
        </div>
    ))}
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue today, and after a bit of poking around found the solution to be surprisingly simple.

```
.glider-track {
    margin: auto;
}
```

The div .glider-track is added to the dom as a wrapper for your slides so centring them within this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
.glide * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Add this to your CSS so it will make your content in the center.